# Setting focus on an input in a custom React dropdown component

Tags: reactjs

I have built a dropdown component that functions as a dropdown list with a search bar.

When the dropdown is toggled open I want to set focus on the search bar.

I added a useRef to the input but found that on the toggle open event it was not set.
If I toggled the dropdown again the ref was set but setting focus had no effect.

After some research I found that I may need to wrap the input with a forwardRef, so I did that as shown below, however it has the same behavior as the standard useRef.

I now suspect that the issue is that on dropdown toggle (open) the input has not yet rendered so there is nothing to ref, and even if there were focus cannot be set.

The docs indicate that in this case a useEffect may be used since it is fired after the DOM is rendered, great, but I don't know how to trigger a useEffect when the input gets 'rendered' in my specific case of a dropdown toggle opening and rendering it's content.

My goal is that when the user opens the dropdown and ParentInput is fully rendered that it gets focus automatically.

It seems I need a way to determine (and handle) when the input has fully rendered after the user opens the dropdown toggle.

Here is the main parts of the code:

```
import React, { useState, useEffect, useContext, forwardRef, useRef } from 'react';
import { Dropdown, ButtonGroup, FormControl } from 'react-bootstrap';

...

//the search bar broken out and wrapped in a forward ref
const ParentInput = forwardRef((props, ref) => {
    return <FormControl {...props} ref={ref} />
});

...

//the drop down toggle event handler
const parentToggled = (isOpen) => {
    if (isOpen) {
        const filtered = allParents.filter(option =>
        option.label.toLowerCase().includes(parentSearchTerm.toLowerCase())
        );
        setParentsFiltered(filtered.slice(0, SCROLL_SIZE));
        if (parentRef && parentRef.current != null) {
            console.log("setting parent focus");
            parentRef.current.focus();
        }
    }
};

//the component
const CompaniesNav = () => {

...

return (
<>
  <Dropdown as={ButtonGroup} onToggle={parentToggled}>
    <Dropdown.Toggle variant="company" id="dropdown-basic" >
      <div className="dropdown-container">
        <div className="dropdown-title">Company Parent</div>
        <div className="dropdown-value">{selectedParent ? selectedParent : "Select..."}</div>
        <div className="dropdown-clear" onClick={clearParentDropdown}><i className="fa fa-close" /></div>
        <span className="dropdown-line"></span>
        <div className="dropdown-caret"><i className="fa fa-chevron-down" /></div>
      </div>
    </Dropdown.Toggle>

    <Dropdown.Menu variant='company'>
      <ParentInput
        ref={ parentRef }
        id="parentInput"
        type="text"
        placeholder="Search..."
        value={parentSearchTerm}
        onChange={handleParentSearch}
      />
      {/*<FormControl*/}
      {/*  ref={parentRef}*/}
      {/*  id="parentInput"*/}
      {/*  type="text"*/}
      {/*  placeholder="Search..."*/}
      {/*  value={parentSearchTerm}*/}
      {/*  onChange={handleParentSearch}*/}
      {/*/>*/}
      <Dropdown.Divider />
      {parentsFiltered.length !== 0 ? parentsFiltered.map((option) => (
        <Dropdown.Item eventKey={option.value} key={option.value} onClick={() => filterParent(option.value, option.label)} href="#">{option.label}</Dropdown.Item>
      )) : <><Dropdown.Item eventKey="1" href="#">Empty</Dropdown.Item></>}
    </Dropdown.Menu>
  </Dropdown>

...

}
```

EDIT:

I had the idea to add the ref to a useEffect, but it does not change the behavior.

```
useEffect(() => {
    if (parentRef && parentRef.current != null) {
        console.log("setting parent focus");
        parentRef.current.focus();
    }
}, [parentRef]);
```

Comment: Are you using a library for the dropdown or is that your own component?

Comment: It is my own component. the only library in use is react bootstrap.

Answer (score 0):

I came up with a simple solution for this, I created a boolean `useState` that toggles when the dropdown is opened, then a useEffect for this toggle that sets the focus. So by the time the `useEffect` is called the DOM is rendered.

I removed the `forwardRef` since it is not needed, a standard `useRef` works here.

There may be a better react way to do this or maybe this is it. It works.

```
const parentRef = useRef(null);
const [parentFocusToggle, setParentFocusToggle] = useState(false);

useEffect(() => {
  if (parentRef && parentRef.current != null) {
    console.log("setting parent focus");
    parentRef.current.focus();
  }
}, [parentFocusToggle]);


const parentToggled = (isOpening) => {
  if (isOpening) {
    console.log("parentToggled");
    setParentFocusToggle(!parentFocusToggle);
  }
};

...

<FormControl
  ref={parentRef}
  id="parentInput"
  type="text"
  placeholder="Search..."
  value={parentSearchTerm}
  onChange={handleParentSearch}
/>
```